# Jacobian Matrix in 'Polar Coordinates'..?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I'm pretty familiar with the [del operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formulae) and I've just become familiar with the Jacobian Matrix. From my basic understanding of what the Jacobian Matrix is, the gradient is a subset of the Jacobian Matrix.

So, how would you get a gradient from the Jacobian Matrix? Also, since there is a such thing as "the gradient in polar coordinates", is there a such thing as "the jacobian matrix in polar coordinates" as well?

Clearly I'm going about this all wrong. Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all the basic Del formulas you seek can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates).
In general, you can use parameters for your Cartesian coordinates and then calculate the determinant of the Jacobian derivative matrix.
In case of polar coordinates: $(x=rcos\theta,y=rsin\theta )$ and then calculate the Jacobian matrix the same way you usually do. 1st column is r, 2nd column is $\theta$. For further reading you can read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Examples).

Regarding the gradient: each row $i$ in the Jacobian Matrix is the gradient of $f_i$, this is the case in general when we speak of a vector-field.

further explanation:
In polar coordinates - your Jacobian Matrix will be $n\times 2$. The first column being $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial r}$ until $\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial r}$ whilst the 2nd column is  $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial \theta}$ until $\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial \theta}$.

In physics, by using this Jacobian Matrix you can calculate "the Jacobian" $r$ [meters] (for polar) which fills the role of filling the "unit" gap when you switch between coordinates in order to use parameters and solve integrals. $\iint dxdy=\iint rdrd\theta$.
Also in spherical coordinates you get $r^2\sin\phi drd\theta d\phi$ for that same reason.

**Mathematics behind the grad formula in polar coordinates:**
$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}\sin\theta\\
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial \theta}=-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}r\sin\theta+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}r\cos\theta\\
$$
We can use those two equations to get:
$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial r}=\cos\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\sin\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=-\sin\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\cos\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
$$
if you write those two linear equations in a matrix you get the definition of gradient in polar coordinates.
$$
\pmatrix{\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial r}\\\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}}=\pmatrix{\cos\theta&sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta}\pmatrix{\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}}
$$
Since this is an orthogonal matrix we know that the $A^T=A^{-1}$ so we get:
$$
\pmatrix{\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial y}}=\pmatrix{\cos\theta&-sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta}\pmatrix{\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial r}\\\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}}=\pmatrix{\cos\theta\\\sin\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\pmatrix{-\sin\theta\\\cos\theta}\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\\
\nabla = \hat r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \hat \theta \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}
$$

Comment: This isn't really an answer. The links you provided are the exact same ones I provided.

Comment: Pardon me, I hadn't clicked on your links. Added my explanation regarding the Jacobian Matrix's connection to gradient.

Comment: Your last paragraph really helps. But, my last question remains unanswered. Is there a such thing as "the Jacobian Matrix in Polar coordinates? (similar to the gradient in polar coordinates)

Comment: I've edited my original response and tried to be as through as I could, without confusing.

Comment: It took me a long time, but I've written down the calculations behind the transformation. I hope this makes it all simple to understand.